# How do you extract numbers from an input file and use them for any output you want?

Tags: java

Suppose I have an input file (text file) with information arranged in the following way: The first 5 numbers will be a, b, c, m, and n. a and b are (domain, range) values for set R1 such that (1, 2...a), (1, 2...b). The number m is for the number of lines (new lines/of code) following these first 5 numbers for which given ordered pairs follow (or dont follow) a possible function for set R1. The number n is for the number of lines (after m lines) which cohere (or dont) to the rules of following a function in set R2 (1, 2...b), (1, 2...c).

Example input file:

1 3 5 2 1

(1, 3)

(1, 2)

(4, 5)

Now I have to make a Java program that takes a text file in that specific format and determines, and gives an output of:

1. Yes, if the ordered pairs for set **R1** are a function and NO otherwise.
2. Yes, if the ordered pairs for set **R2** are a function and NO otherwise.
3. Yes, if the ordered pairs for set **R1** are a function and it is onto. NA if it is not a function. NO if it is a function and not onto.
4. Yes, if the ordered pairs for set **R2** are a function and it is onto. NA if it is not a function. NO if it is a function and not onto.
5. If both are functions then compute the function g ◦ f and output it as pairs
   where the first coordinate in the pair
   are in sorted order. For example, if g
   ◦ f maps 1 to 10, 2 to 4 and 3 to 15 your code must output for this part, the
   following three lines.
   (1,10)
   (2,4)
   (3,15)
   If any one of them is not a function, then just output NA for this part.

So far all I know how to do is print, as an output, all the data given in the input file.. i dunno how to pick specific parts from the input file and use it to see if a function is possible for a specific domain.. how would I even do that..?

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;

public class prob1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("TestCase.txt");

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                String num = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println(num);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.format("File does not exist\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've imported `java.io.File`, you don't need to use the fully qualified name to reference it; just `File` will suffice unless there is a conflicting class in the scope (which there isn't).

Comment: To "extract" the numbers from the input file you will need to use a combination of [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

You have `String num = input.nextLine();` so now you just need to manipulate this `num` string using the methods of the `String` class.

For example since you said

> The first 5 numbers will be a, b, c, m, and n

you might do something like:

```
int a = -1, b = -1, c = -1, m = -1, n = -1;
...
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String num = input.nextLine().trim(); //I added trim to remove any extraneous whitespace
    //I'm assuming if one variable has not been initialized then none
    //  have since they all appear on the same line of the input file.
    //Also assuming that a, b, c, m, and n will always be positive 
    //  once they have been initialized.
    if(a < 0){
        String[] parts = num.split(" ");
        if(parts.length == 5){
            a = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            c = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            m = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
            n = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
        }else{
            //There's a problem - more or less items than expected
            // so you will need to handle that somehow.
        }
    }
    ...
    //Processing for the ordered pairs...
    ...
    System.out.println(num);
}
...
//You'll probably want to handle the case where you get a 
//  NumberFormatException when the call to Integer.parseInt
//  fails. This can happen if the string passed to parseInt 
//  does not contain a valid integer value.
```